# How to hold CSS styles when using Zajax Wordpress plugin to load pages via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, wordpress

I've searched for weeks looking for a definitive answer to this problem and it remains unanswered; when I initially land on the homepage of a site I'm building with AJAX page loading the CSS appears fine. If I navigate to another page the CSS styling is incorrect. If I refresh the page it comes back. I understand the concept of AJAX in that it pulls the data and does not apply the styles. Is there a way to refresh the CSS styles (they should be global) without having to refresh the entire page?

Most people suggest checking CSS validity (which I have done) but I have seen others mention site cache issues. I did initially post this question to the plugin support forum but as it's unsupported now, so got no reply. The plugin admin section has 2 sections where you can add Javascript or jQuery code; 'On AJAX Send' & 'On AJAX Complete'. I've tried numerous suggestions, refreshing the CSS via js but that then drops the AJAX page loading capability, so no good.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: can you share a link?

Comment: 1) you should provide a reproducable example / link

2) are you sure you're loading scripts first when the document is ready?

Comment: It's a dev site so unfortunately cannot share a link. It seems a straightforward enough scenario of using AJAX to load page data into the #content div. I've also tried Advanced AJAX Page Loader & AJAXify plugins and all throw the same error. Seems like an obvious problem to fix but no answers appear to have been published. I found this article a while back but there was no solution given: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252640/advanced-ajax-page-loader-aapl-blocks-resources

Comment: Seems odd - I use Zajax and although I get some problems with scripts which don't reload, my CSS is fine (used in the normal WP way and not added to the Zajax settings). Without more info, I suspect your theme may be the problem. What errors are shown from 'inspect element'?

Comment: @gulliver I think you're right. I'm using generatepress pro which generates inline styles from the Customiser section. The author said it's not page specific but have seen differences between them. I tried to collate all into one file and append that to the head section upon ajax complete but that has no effect. Am so frustrated by not understanding the flow of this.

Comment: I have another plugin for tooltips and even that's CSS gets messed up after an AJAX page load. Thought to try a different plugin Ajaxify (AWS) and that loaded the blog fine but then couldn't handle other page's JS files! Seems like someone could do well to produce an AJAX page loading plugin that actually accommodates all variable scenarios.

Comment: @deeve ... late getting notifications, so only just seen your comments. I share your desire for an appropriate plugin. Zajax was the only one I could get to work, although I think the developer of Ajaxify WordPress Site(AWS) was helpful and got his plugin to work.